# asp.net dropdown blank values in ie8 fetched with jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8

I have asp.net dropdown which is populated in jQuery from asp.net web method. I am able to see the data as it should in IE9+, FF, Chrome as shown on the image below:

[image]

In IE8 this is what I get:

[image]

Viewing the source of the page, I can see both the text and the value but I am getting blank values on the screen.
This is the web method I am using:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<TraceabilityData> fetchData(int orderlineBomId)
{
    Assembly _ass = new Assembly();
    Dictionary<string, string> List = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var values = new List<TraceabilityData>();
    List = _ass.traceabilityDataset(orderlineBomId);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> val in List)
    {
        values.Add(new TraceabilityData { Id = Convert.ToInt32(val.Key), Content = val.Value });
    }
    return values;
}
```

And the jQuery function:

```
 $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "Index.aspx/fetchData",
                      data: "{orderlineBomId: '" + orderlinebomid + "'}",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function (response) {
                          var dropdown = $('#<%=ddlTraceability.ClientID %>');
                          dropdown.empty();
                          dropdown.append(new Option(" ", 0));
                          $.each(response.d, function (index, item) {
                              dropdown.append(new Option(item.Content, item.Id));
                          });
                      },
                      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                          console.log("Ajax Error");
                          alert(xhr.responseText);
                      }
                  });
```

What can I try next?

Comment: What's the `Option` object look like? Have you compared the rendered html sources for each browser? IE8 probably doesn't like how you are displaying the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.In cases like this I use this method to make IE8 happy

Change your success callback  function to this

```
 success:  function (response) {
                      var dropdown = $('#<%=ddlTraceability.ClientID %>');
                      dropdown.empty();
                      dropdown.append($('<option></option>').val("0").html("");
                      $.each(response.d, function (index, item) {
               dropdown.append( $('<option></option>').val(item.Id).html(item.Content));

                      });
                  },
```